# Where to find P.K.leelamma's translation of the Devi Shapthasathi into english online?

Tags: resource, chandipath

Is the book written by Smt P K Leelamma on Devi Mahathmyam available online?  please let me know thru email. It is a Ramakrishna Mission Trissur publication of the 1930s.

Comment: Is this the one: https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/shakti-pooja-malayalam-MZF492/ ? It's in Malayalam though

Comment: Sending links of books thru email is not something that we do here. But if you simply ask whether this particular book is available online or not then that's a valid question for our site. BTW welcome here :)

Comment: I have removed the Puranas tag for the question as it does not seem to be necessary. Devi Mahatyam is also known as Chadipatha so I have added that tag. Apparently there is no "Devi Mahatyam" tag here.